# Styled elements 'input[type="submit"]' and 'button' have different widths than other elements

Tags: css, html, button

It's easy to workaround by giving the widths different numerical values (and thus an equal visible width) but this just bugs me a lot.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.box {
    width: 6em;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:inherit;
    text-align:center;
    color:inherit;
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<html>
<body>
<a class="box">Anchor</a>
<input type="submit" class="box" value="Input" />
<button type="submit" class="box">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRmtp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the same width, by adding the rule:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TRmtp/2/).

The problem is the way the browsers assign widths, specifically whether the `width` includes the padding, and border, widths. Using `box-sizing: border-box` forces the (compliant) browsers to include those widths within the overall assigned width, regardless of the 'default' model.

References:

- [`box-sizing` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`box-width` (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-box-20021024/#the-box-width).

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Is there a reason why the widths are assigned differently?